# WPF: Notify visualParent when its children changed their size

Tags: wpf

I have FrameworkElement, for example Grid, that has children(Cells, implemented in another control). When main Window changes size, i handle sizeChanged in Grid at first, and after that in some of its children. How can i get notify that all children sizeChanged events finished processing? Of course, i can raise other event in child sizeChanged and increase some counter, but for some reasons it is not the best decision.

Can anyone recommend something? Thanks!

Comment: I think if you instead describe what in general you are trying to accomplish, there may be a more elegant solution.  Perhaps involving some way to make things automatically change on a property value or event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [UIElement.LayoutUpdated Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.layoutupdated.aspx).  It fires whenever the layout gets updated which is a lot, so I would suggest subscribing to it in a handler for the containers SizeChanged event and unsubscribe in the LayoutUpdated handler.

Example:

```
    private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Size change started.
        LayoutUpdated += Window_LayoutUpdated;
    }

    private void Window_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Size change completed.
        LayoutUpdated -= Window_LayoutUpdated;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like it works the way i need. Big thanks!

The sense of my question was to set same font sizes(based on cell sizes) in different groups of cells in all tables(grids) in window.